# Node.js V8 Mark-sweep optimization?

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection, v8, event-loop

It seems that for my server mark-sweep operation takes seconds in stop-the-world way:

```
Oct 17 08:26:27 s3 u[30843]: [30843:0x26671a0] 63025059 ms: Mark-sweep 2492.7 (3285.6) -> 2317.6 (2945.0) MB, 84.9 / 0.1 ms  (+ 3223.4 ms in 3877 steps since start of marking, biggest step 731.7 ms, walltime since start of marking 3315 ms) finalize incremental marking via task GC in old space requested
Oct 17 08:26:27 s3 u[30843]: Execution blocked for 3273 ms
.
Oct 17 08:28:15 s3 u[30843]: [30843:0x26671a0] 63133051 ms: Mark-sweep 2499.8 (3298.4) -> 2313.4 (2947.1) MB, 160.2 / 0.1 ms  (+ 3691.7 ms in 3679 steps since start of marking, biggest step 1073.4 ms, walltime since start of marking 3859 ms) finalize incremental marking via task GC in old space requested
Oct 17 08:28:15 s3 u[30843]: Execution blocked for 3791 ms
.
```

This behavior is similar than described in https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/947, it seems to be somewhat related to memory consumption and worsens over time.

The problem existed in node 7, but was only barely noticeable. Now with node 8.12 it reaches 5 sec block within 24 h.

I suspected it might have something to do with unorthodox way of storing data in big objects, tried to reconstruct one 2 GB object to smaller objects cutting it down to 1 GB, but no obvious benefit. However, these objects are very simple while big.

The questions are:

- Is there an V8 option to make mark-sweep to mitigate this problem? Less often, smaller steps, skip some optimizations, anything?
- I could not find any decent documentation about V8 options - is there?
- How to help mark-sweep to do it's task more efficiently?
- Are there common cases what to avoid where mark-sweep could struggle?
- Any desperate hacks I could try?

Comment: I'd suggest logging an issue on the Node issue tracker. Did you try the steps from issue 947 which you linked? It could be the same problem. Can you try with Node 10?

Comment: Can not use node 10 because it's does not handle express+http2, yet, afaik.

Comment: This seems to be fixed in Node 10.